# Get data from API call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, button, sugarcrm, window.open

I am new to JS and I want to open a new window when I click on my button in SugarCRM without browser blocking it.

```
function authenticateCalendar() {
    var result;
    var url = app.api.buildURL("Users", 'authenticate_calendar');
    app.api.call('retrieve', url, null, {
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.needAuth) {
                result = JSON.parse(data.url) ;
            }
            else result = false;
        }
    });
    if(result)
        window.open(result);
}
<input type="button" onclick="authenticateCalendar();">
```

Is it possible to get the `data.url` string in my function?

Comment: Call `window.open()` inside the `success:` function.

Comment: I cant, because then the browser will block the new page

Comment: You mean the popup blocker? The alternative is to open the new window immediately, and put the script that loads the page into that window.